# I'm trying to change the background color on my website

Tags: html, css, flask

I'm currently following a tutorial on learning to make a login/registration system using Flask. I'm trying to edit the background color on my style.css file but when I do nothing happens. I have my files setup like this

```
\-- pythonlogin
  |-- main.py
  \-- static
    |-- style.css
  \-- templates
    |-- index.html
    |-- register.html
    |-- home.html
    |-- profile.html
    |-- layout.html
```

my register.html is like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="login">
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <div class="links">
                <a href="{{ url_for('login') }}" class="active">Login</a>
                <a href="#">Register</a>
            </div>
            <form action="{{ url_for('login') }}" method="post">
                <label for="username">
                    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                </label>
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" id="username" required>
                <label for="password">
                    <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                </label>
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" required>
                <div class="msg">{{ msg }}</div>
                <input type="submit" value="Login">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

for my style.css:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "segoe ui", roboto, oxygen, ubuntu, cantarell, "fira sans", "droid sans", "helvetica neue", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
body {
    background-color: #435165;
    margin: 0;
}
.login, .register {
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 9px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    margin: 100px auto;
}
.login h1, .register h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #5b6574;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dee0e4;
}
.login .links, .register .links {
    display: flex;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
.login .links a, .register .links a {
    color: #adb2ba;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-flex;
    padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.login .links a:hover, .register .links a:hover {
    color: #9da3ac;
}
.login .links a.active, .register .links a.active {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #3274d6;
    color: #3274d6;
}
.login form, .register form {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.login form label, .register form label {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #3274d6;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.login form input[type="password"], .login form input[type="text"], .login form input[type="email"], .register form input[type="password"], .register form input[type="text"], .register form input[type="email"] {
    width: 310px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #dee0e4;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
.login form input[type="submit"], .register form input[type="submit"] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: #3274d6;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffff;
    transition: background-color 0.2s;
}
.login form input[type="submit"]:hover, .register form input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background-color: #2868c7;
    transition: background-color 0.2s;
}
.navtop {
    background-color: #2f3947;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
}
.navtop div {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100%;
}
.navtop div h1, .navtop div a {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.navtop div h1 {
    flex: 1;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #eaebed;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.navtop div a {
    padding: 0 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #c1c4c8;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.navtop div a i {
    padding: 2px 8px 0 0;
}
.navtop div a:hover {
    color: #eaebed;
}
body.loggedin {
    background-color: #f3f4f7;
}
.content {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.content h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 25px 0;
    font-size: 22px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e3;
    color: #4a536e;
}
.content > p, .content > div {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    margin: 25px 0;
    padding: 25px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.content > p table td, .content > div table td {
    padding: 5px;
}
.content > p table td:first-child, .content > div table td:first-child {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #4a536e;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
.content > div p {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
```

I want to change the background-color to #ff0000 but when I do nothing happens, I tried doing this with others but nothing is happening. The link to the tutorial I'm following is https://codeshack.io/login-system-python-flask-mysql/

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

In style.css ,
change the background color in body. By doing so, it applies to all parts of webpage.
`body {`
 `background-color: #ff0000;`
 `margin: 0;`
`}`

Link the syle.css to all html files to add the same background color to the web page.

Comment: I figured it out I had to do an "Empty Cache and Hard Reload ".